# Fibbonaci series using Arrow Functions

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a code for fibbonaci series using arrow function....But is too complex...
Is there any other way to find the fibbonaci series using arrow functions only??

```js
var n = Number(prompt("Enter limit: "));
const fibonacci = n =>
  Array.from({
    length: n
  }).reduce(
    (acc, val, i) => acc.concat(i > 1 ? acc[i - 1] + acc[i - 2] : i), []
  );
console.log("Fibonnaci series: ");
console.log(fibonacci(n));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use recursion to build the sequence from bottom up:

```js
fibs = n => fibs2([0, 1], n - 2)

fibs2 = (a, n) => n === 0 ? a
    : fibs2(a.concat(a[a.length - 2] + a[a.length - 1]), n - 1)

console.log(...fibs(50))
```

Comment: But i want the user to enter the limit of numbers he wants

Comment: I have but it seems too complex..so i wanted an easier way using arrow functions

Comment: Just replace "50" above with `Number(prompt("Enter limit: "))`

Answer (score 2):

I tried with code like this and it works, maybe you can practice it

```
const getNearestFibonacci = (param) => {
  const number = param.reduce((accumulator, value) => accumulator + value);
  let fib = [0, 1];
  do {
    fib = [...fib, fib[fib.length - 1] + fib[fib.length - 2]];
  } while (fib[fib.length - 1] < number);

  const before = fib[fib.length - 2];
  console.log(before);
  const after = fib[fib.length - 1];
  console.log(after);
  return Math.abs(before - number) < after - number
    ? before - number
    : after - number;
};
```